# Convert .h5 file to .jpg with Python

Tags: python, jpeg, hdf5, image-conversion

I currently have a .h5 file containing grayscale imagery. I need to convert it to a .jpg.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

*Note: I could possible convert the h5 file to a numpy array and then use an external library like pypng to convert that to a png. But I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to convert to an image, and preferrably a .jpg.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key ingredients:

h5py to read the h5 file.
Determine the format of your image and use PIL.

Let us suppose it's RGB format (https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/UsersGuide/ug06imageview.html)

Suppose your image is located at Photos/Image 1 then you can do.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

hdf = h5py.File("Sample.h5",'r')
array = hdf["Photos/Image 1"][:]
img = Image.fromarray(array.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
img.save("yourimage.thumbnail", "JPEG")
img.show()
```

Comment: `array = hdf["Photos/Image 1"][:]`.  `h5py` loads datasets as numpy arrays.  No need for that `array(list(...)))` dance.