# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (h5 file)

Tags: python, jpeg, h5py, file-conversion

I am fighting with python for a school project. I copied and pasted some code from [this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394252/convert-h5-file-to-jpg-with-python) changing only the variable names. I am trying to convert two files from h5 to jpg. Here is my code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

hdf = h5py.File("train_happy.h5",'r')
array = np.array(list(hdf.get("train_happy.h5")))
img = Image.fromarray(array.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
img.save("train_happy.jpg", "JPEG")

hdf2 = h5py.File("test_happy.h5",'r')
array = np.array(list(hdf2.get("test_happy.h5")))
img = Image.fromarray(array.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
img.save("test_happy.jpg", "JPEG")

training = 'train_happy.jpg'
testing = 'test_happy.jpg'
```

I know absolutely nothing about h5 files or converting files using python. Please help!

EDIT: Here is the line the error was on:

```
array = np.array(list(hdf.get("train_happy.h5")))
```

If I had to guess, I would say the same error will happen on this line:

```
array = np.array(list(hdf2.get("test_happy.h5")))
```

Also, the command:

```
print(list(hdf.keys()))
```

gives me this output:

```
['list_classes', 'train_set_x', 'train_set_y']
```

Comment: You can quickly learn about **h5py** module from here [Quick Start With h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html)

Comment: Please create a minimal complete verifiable example along with the **exact** error.

Comment: Do you want us to guess what line the error is on? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I guess `hdf.get("train_happy.h5")` or `hdf2.get("test_happy.h5")` are returning `None` and you are trying to convert to a `list`.

Comment: What does `print(list(hdf.keys()))` give you? Edit the question, I'm not here to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the example in your linked post!
Your initial error is this in line:

```
array = np.array(list(hdf.get("train_happy.h5")))
```

`train_happy.h5` is the **name of the HDF5 file**. You need to use the **name of the image dataset** in the HDF5 file (using group/dataset nomenclature). The output from `list(hdf.keys())` indicates you have 3 nodes at the root level. Each node is either a Group or a Dataset (an image). Without knowing exactly what you have, it's hard to write the next step. Ideally you would use `.isinstance()` to get the node type. A very simple example is provided below to loop thru your node names:

```
for node in list(hdf.keys()) :
    print ('working on node %s' % node)
    object = hdf[node]
    if (isinstance(object, h5py.Group)):
        print ('%s is a Group' % node )
    elif (isinstance(object, h5py.Dataset)):
        print ('%s is a Dataset' % node )
```

Or, you could simply hack away and try this (adjusting downstream code appropriately): [code below modified per hpaulj's comments]

```
array_x = hdf.get["train_set_x"][:]
array_y = hdf.get["train_set_y"][:]
```

The code above assumes that `train_set_x` and `train_set_y` are image datasets (similar to `"Photos/Image 1"` in your link).

Also, you DO NOT need the second hdf2 declaration (`hdf2 = h5py.File("test_happy.h5",'r')`) to process a second image. You can reuse `hdf` each time, and change the name of the Group/Dataset reference as shown for `array_y` above.

Comment: For a Dataset name, `array_x = hdf['train_set_x'][:]` should be all that's needed to load the array.  `hdf` and `groups` behave like Python dictionaries.  Datasets index like numpy arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj. Good point. Thanks. I was in a hurry and simply copied the OPs code (shame on me). I will modify my example to reflect your comments